# Diagonal shape in Python using while loops

Tags: python, diagonal

I am working on a basic shapes program in Python and can't seem to work out my code. I need to keep it simple using while loops and the variables given, nested loops are usable.

Here is my code for a square:

```
def drawSquare(size, drawingChar):
    print('Square: ')
    row = 1
    while row <= size:
       # Output a single row
       drawRow(size, drawingChar)

       # Output a newline to end the row
       print()

       # The next row number
       row = row + 1

     print()
```

It is supposed to print like:

```
x
  x
    x
      x
```

based on a size and character entered by the user.

drawRow is another function similar to drawSquare:

```
def drawRow(size, drawingChar):
    col = 1
    while col <= size:
       print(drawingChar, end=' ')

col = col + 1
```

Comment: So two questions. What is your function `drawRow`? What is it currently printing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, it is a Question and Answer site where you can ask a **specific** programming question that **can be answered** rather than discussed. Your post is missing the most important part - a question. Without one, you are very unlikely to get a helpful response. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @VaibhavSanjay I edited the post to include the drawRow function

Comment: I can't really understand your logic in your `drawRow` method, since it would print the same thing each time it is called. Also, your code is not printing anything because `drawRow` has an infinite while loop in it. The value of column is not actually being updated inside the loop. I would suggest using the code of one of the other answers.

Comment: drawRow was a prewritten function given to me and is completely functional. It is printing, I just can't figure out how to print a Diagonal shape/the logic within it, but other shapes such as triangles and rectangles were simple enough and worked.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't copy the code incorrectly? Take a look at the while loop in the question you submitted. if size is greater than 1, it is going to infinitely print `drawingChar` . I just want to make sure we can see the right code.

Answer (score 0):

It would make more sense with a for loop:

```
def drawSquare(size, drawingChar):
    for i in range(size):
        print(" "*i + drawingChar)
```

Example:

`drawSquare(4, "p")`

Output:

```
p
 p
  p
   p
```

Answer (score 0):

Please *show your work* for drawDiagonal (or anything) when asking a question.

Diagonal is probably the easier case here:

```
def drawDiagonal(size, drawingChar):
    for y in range(size):
        s = ' '* y + drawingChar
        print(s)

drawDiagonal(4,"X")
```

`X
 X
  X
   X`

(Maybe pick a fixed font)

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with is:

```
def drawDiagonal(size, drawingChar):
    print('Diagonal: ')
    row = 1
    while row <= size:
        # Output a single row
        drawRow(row - 1, ' ')
        print(drawingChar)

        # Output a newline to end the row
        print()

        # The next row number
        row = row + 1

     print()
```

Note: drawRow is defined separately (above, in question) 
& drawDiagonal was called separately as well:

```
drawDiagonal(userSize, userChar)
```

where

```
userSize = input('Size: ')
userChar = input('Character: ')
```